How to customize a multiple search engines from different online databases for free?
There are several search boxes from different online databases (libraries) that I need to join into a single one.
As an example with just two URLs, searching the word "cervantes" in each returns as follows (check the different books each database holds):

https://castillalamancha.ebiblio.es/resources?q=cervantes
https://galicia.ebiblio.es/resources?q=cervantes

I've tried Google's programmable search engine, adding up the different urls up to the ?q= sequence, but it did not work: no finds were returned.
What alternatives do I have?

Please share how you customized Google's Programmable Search. What was the result? The last question you ask is for us to recommend alternative search engines: This sort of question is off topic on this site.  Please EDIT your post to clarify an on-topic question. If you're unsure what is on topic, the Help section can help you.
